# Copy and paste excel file contents from one excel to another and also preserve the hyperlinks using python

Tags: python, selenium, openpyxl, xlwings

I am trying to copy contents from a source excel file to destination excel file. So my source excel file has hyperlinks in it. But when I paste the source file contents to destination excel file the hyperlinks are gone.

Is there any way to preserve the hyperlinks???

**CODE**:

```
import openpyxl as xl;

# opening the source excel file

filename ="C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\trading.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

# opening the destination excel file

filename1 ="C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\test.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.active

# calculate total number of rows and
# columns in source excel file

mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

# copying the cell values from source
# excel file to destination excel file

for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):

        # reading cell value from source excel file

        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)

        # writing the read value to destination excel file

        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value

# saving the destination excel file

wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).hyperlink = c.hyperlink` after `ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value`.

Do the same thing with `.style` if you want to preserve the blue colour of the links.